# SAP .NET Connector 3 with both R3 and ECC

Tags: c#, sap-erp, sap-dotnet-connector, sap-r3

I have made an application to connect SAP R3 using SAP .NET Connector 3.

Now, I have another situation need connecting SAP ECC, but I don't make sure it can work.

Anyone knows, does SAP .NET Connector 3 support the version both **SAP R3** and **SAP ECC**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does support both - SAP ECC is just the new name for the later versions of what was SAP R/3.

Note that the newest versions are labelled "S/4 Hana", and this can also work with the SAP .NET Connnector v3, though certain newer functionality might require up-to-date versions of the Connector.